# Application Insights - Distinct Users and the last time they visited the site

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a query that can be run to find distinct users and the last time they visited your app on Application Insights? Running just distinct users on the pageViews query shows the distinct users, but doesn't show the timestamp column.

Comment: please add your query, and it's better if you can add a screenshot.

Comment: The query I have (albeit simple) is 'pageViews | distinct users'. Running that only shows the distinct users... but I want to add the timestamp for those distinct users as well for the last time they used the app.

Comment: Yes Ivan! Thanks. That works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query you provided `pageViews | distinct users`, I don't know where the field `users` come from, because there is no such field in my `pageViews` table.

So I used the `user_Id` instead of `users` in the query. The query is as below:

```
pageViews 
| project user_Id , timestamp
| summarize max(timestamp) by user_Id
```

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the screenshot to go to logs query view on Application Insights resource. There is a timestamp column in the pageViews table which you can query to find out when did the users last visited.

[image]