# Dynamic userId in kusto query Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm new with Azure Application Insights service, I want to get data from my app (developed with Xamarin Forms, c#) and I need to make a specific query to be able to get a user stats and display it on my Azure Dashboard. I'm able to make this request for all users but not for one user. I show you my query

```
 customEvents 
 | where name == "LoggedUserEvent"
 | where timestamp > now() - 31d
 | extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
 | extend userId = todouble(todecimal(Properties.UserId))
 | where userId == XXX
 | summarize Total = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
 | project Total, timestamp
```

this query work's well and show me Total and timestamp as you can see

[image: Proof]

but the issue it's I should specify

```
  | where userId == XXX
```

Each time I want new data about specific user I have to update this line, is there en easier way to get this info using an input text for example or if you have any suggestions, salespeople will use this platform and need to be simple as possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement you can try with `page view` method so that we can get specific users who logged in to your application instead of using `Custom events`.

Example of query:

```
pageViews 
| project user_Id , timestamp
| summarize max(timestamp) by user_Id
```

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***SO THREAD*** : [***Application Insights - Distinct Users and the last time they visited the site***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617741/application-insights-distinct-users-and-the-last-time-they-visited-the-site) & [***Trying to create a KQL with users who have not logged in within the last 30 days***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033332/trying-to-create-a-kql-with-users-who-have-not-logged-in-within-the-last-30-days)